# Using some column data for values and some for ID

Tags: sql, plsql

Slowly but surely I'm getting the hang of this.  I created a report using the following query, which works perfectly.  I'll give an example of the result below the query.

```
Select p.parent_program_id, p.program_id, p.name, p.copyright, p.active_flag,
       max(Case when c.category_id = 36261 Then 'X' Else ' ' End) As CC_Indicator,
       max(Case when c1.category_id = 36362 Then 'X' Else ' ' End) As CC_Badge,
       max(Case when c2.category_id = 43221 Then 'X' Else ' ' End) As CC_Solution
From tbl_program p
Join xref_category_program xcp
  On p.program_id=xcp.program_id
left Join tbl_category c
  On xcp.category_id=c.category_id and c.category_id = 36261 
left Join tbl_category c1
  On xcp.category_id=c1.category_id and c1.category_id = 36362 
left Join tbl_category c2
  On xcp.category_id=c2.category_id and c2.category_id = 43221
where xcp.category_id in(36261,36362,43221)
group by p.program_id, p.name, p.copyright, p.active_flag, p.parent_program_id
Order by p.program_id
```

The results look like this (leaving out some unimportant columns for brevity's sake):

```
P.ParentProgramID  P.ProgramID   CC_Indicator  CC_Badge  CC_Solution
00001              12111         X                   
null               20200         X             X         X
null               00001         X             X
```

The Indicator/Badge/Solution is identified by a category id.  Now the people requesting this report want it sorted by company, which are also assigned category ids in the same column.

Assuming something like xcp.category_id values for company were 11111/22222/33333/44444, how would I put that in another column in this report in an order decided by the receivers of the report?

Something that looked like this, assuming a total of 6 records...

```
P.ParentProgramID  P.ProgramID   CC_Indicator  CC_Badge  CC_Solution  Region
00001              12111         X                                    44444
null               20200         X             X         X            44444
null               00001         X             X                      22222
null               32332                                 X            11111
null               44215         X                       X            11111
null               84425                       X                      33333
```

second effort, described as rudimentary below...

```
Select p.parent_program_id, p.program_id, p.name, p.copyright, p.active_flag,
max(decode(c.category_id,36261,'X','')) As CC_Indicator,
max(decode(c1.category_id,36362,'X','')) As CC_Badge,
max(decode(c2.category_id,43221,'X','')) As CC_Solution,
max(decode(c3.category_id,6321,'US','')) As US,
max(decode(c4.category_id,6081,'CA','')) As CA,
max(decode(c5.category_id,35061,'GS','')) As GS
From tbl_program p Join xref_category_program xcp On p.program_id=xcp.program_id
left Join tbl_category c On xcp.category_id=c.category_id and c.category_id = 36261 
left Join tbl_category c1 On xcp.category_id=c1.category_id and c1.category_id = 36362 
left Join tbl_category c2 On xcp.category_id=c2.category_id and c2.category_id = 43221
left Join tbl_category c3 On xcp.category_id=c3.category_id and c3.category_id = 6321
left Join tbl_category c4 On xcp.category_id=c4.category_id and c4.category_id = 6081
left Join tbl_category c5 On xcp.category_id=c5.category_id and c5.category_id = 35061
where xcp.category_id in(36261,36362,43221,6321,6081,35061)
group by p.program_id, p.name, p.copyright, p.active_flag, p.parent_program_id
Order by p.program_id
```

Comment: How would the company ID's be joined into the rest of the data?

Comment: that's what i'm trying to figure out.  it's baffling me because i'm already using xcp.category_id for the values.

Comment: maybe i didn't make this clear.  the column, Region, is populated with data from the same column as the values providing results for CC_Indicator, CC_Badge, and CC_Solution.  they are all category IDs.

Comment: i tried this as a rudimentary way to get it into three columns.  i'm getting data on the GS column, but not on US or CA, even though the bulk would be in US, and CA next.

Comment: ok.  this is working now.  any ideas on how to put all the regions into one column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your query a bit, as follows:

```
Select p.parent_program_id,
       p.program_id,
       p.name,
       p.copyright,
       p.active_flag,
       max(decode(c.category_id,36261,'X','')) As CC_Indicator,
       max(decode(c.category_id,36362,'X','')) As CC_Badge,
       max(decode(c.category_id,43221,'X','')) As CC_Solution,
       max(decode(c.category_id,6321, 'US','')) As US,
       max(decode(c.category_id,6081, 'CA','')) As CA,
       max(decode(c.category_id,35061,'GS','')) As GS
  From tbl_program p
  INNER Join xref_category_program xcp
    On p.program_id = xcp.program_id
  INNER Join tbl_category c
    On xcp.category_id = c.category_id
  where xcp.category_id in (36261, 36362, 43221, 6321, 6081, 35061)
  group by p.program_id, p.name, p.copyright, p.active_flag, p.parent_program_id
  Order by p.program_id
```

I don't think you need the multiple joins of TBL_CATEGORY - one should do it, as you're identifying which categories you want in the WHERE clause.

I'm still at something of a loss as to getting the region ID's in.  It seems that most of the basic data for this query (PROGRAM_ID, etc) comes from TBL_PROGRAM.  Is there a column on TBL_PROGRAM which identifies the region?  You can always make a second join of XREF_CATEGORY_PROGRAM or TBL_CATEGORY, but without knowing what column in the other tables identifies the region I can't help you understand how to get the region data joined in.

Share and enjoy.